# Указатель на массив классов без конструкторов по умолчанию

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть такой класс:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int bar;
    Foo(int b)
    {
        bar = b;
    }
};
```

и вот такой:

```
template<class T>
class Bax
{
private:
    T *data;
public:
    Bax()
    {
        data = new T[4];
    }
};
```

Как переписать 2-й класс так, чтобы заработало

```
Bax<Foo> bax;
Bax<int> bax2;
```

оказалось все намного проще.. просто нужно выделять память не через нью, а через маллок

Comment: в том то и дело, что мне свой вектор написать нужно

Comment: Так, видимо, не сделаете. Создавайте массив указателей T **data. Вообще, посмотрите реализацию какого-нить стандартного контейнера, код stl открыт же.

Answer (score 2):

Штатными средствами не сделать. Можно попробовать new перегрузить для класса Bax, что бы вызывал конструктор с параметром.
Но можно изменить первый класс, добавив конструктор по умолчнию.

```
 class Foo
    {
    public:
        int bar;
        Foo(int b)
        {
            bar = b;
        }
        Foo():bar(0){} // << --- добавить

    };
```

Посмотрите здесь, там дают пару конкретных советов
http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=75910

Comment: Проще всего сделать так:

    Foo(int b = 0)
    {
        bar = b;
    }

Comment: Ну и bar вынести в список инициализации.